# a4j:commandButton can't find its form

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

I have the following code:

```
<h:form id="dispSchedule">
  <a4j:commandButton value="View Full Schedule" 
                     rendered="#{studentClassView.dispClass.getBoolean('class_publish_loc')}"
                     render ="@form"
                     action="#{studentClassView.toggleDisplaySchedule()}"/>
  <rich:extendedDataTable id="fullSchedule" 
    ...
  </rich:extendedDataTable>
</h:form>
```

When I click on the button, the extendedDataTable is displayed but I get this message:

```
The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within <h:form>
```

Any ideas on why it can't find its form?

Comment: Which JSF impl/version are you using? (please always always mention this in all your JSF questions to save us the effort asking this everytime). Older Mojarra versions had bugs related to this. In such case, just upgrading should do.

Comment: Sorry; still new at this. The jar file I'm using is javax.faces-2.1.17.jar. Richfaces is 4.3.0.final.

Comment: Oh, that's then indeed strange. Is that really the code in SSCCE format? I.e. in real code you could also reproduce the very problem yourself using **exactly** the provided code? Shouldn't there actually be more between the `<h:body>` and the `<h:form>` or between the `<h:form>` and the `<a4j:commandButton>`? I also wonder the relevance of the `<rich:extendedDataTable>` in the snippet and the button's attributes as to the concrete problem.

Comment: Actually, I cut it down so that the form only encloses the button and the table. Before that, I had the form sitting right inside the body (actually, there are some template files for header and footer that have their own forms but the form enclosed everything in this file) and with that, it wasn't calling the action method when the button was clicked. The data table has stuff in it but I didn't think that was relevant to this problem. I included the data table inside the form because I was rendering it.

Comment: Tried it again today and it worked without the error. No clue why it started or why it went away. (sigh)